# Plot random intercepts from lmer model

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, lme4

I ran a regression that looks as follows:

```
fit <- lmer(support ~ 1 + (1 | country), data = df, REML = F)
```

I want to plot the varying intercepts for the different countries. I tried with the following code:

```
p1 <- ggplot(fit, aes(support, colour=country)) + geom_line()
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Comment: `ggplot()` needs a data.frame for plotting. I don't know `lmer()` but I would be surprised if it generates a data frame. The package `broom` supports a number of regression models and turns the results into tidy data.frames.

Comment: there are some plot methods, but use `lattice` : `library(lattice) ; dotplot(ranef(fit, condVar=TRUE)) ; dotplot(coef(fit))`. Shouldn't be difficult to grab the relevant data If you really need this in ggplot.

Comment: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#predictions-andor-confidence-or-prediction-intervals-on-predictions gives some plots as well